# NetBeans intellisense and tapping into WordPress API

Tags: php, wordpress, intellisense, netbeans-7

I'm working with WordPress within my project. and I'm using the Netbeans 7.3.1

WordPress has a ton of includes...  and the current file I'm working on ( functions.php) cannot know which other files are involved. So, when I type in say $is_IE ( which is a global) or wp_register_nav which is a wordpress function), because they are not defined within the context of the current functions.php, it cannot give me intelisense support.

In this case, what do we do?

Is there a way in NetBeans which allows me to point to a few specific PHP files in my project so that NetBeans would know about the functions and constants defined in those files and hence, it can extend its intellisense support? - just like it does to native PHP functions, even those those functions are not  within the current file.

Is it possible?

Comment: just realized my original answer totally misread your question. Just updated it - let me know if the new answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WordPress native functions and objects in external files on the same webserver by requiring `wp_load.php` in your header.  Just add this at the top:

`require_once('relative/path/to/wp-load.php');`

Edit: Just realized I read your question completely wrong.  [This link details how to add intellisense support for your Wordpress project.](http://crossplatform.net/adding-wordpress-intellisense-support-to-netbeans-php-project/)  There is also a [WordPress plugin for Netbeans](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-wordpress-plugin/) that may do what you want.

I also know there is a plugin for Sublime Text for WordPress snippets and autocompletions - you can [find it here on Github](https://github.com/purplefish32/sublime-text-2-wordpress).